# removing space for a url string inside a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a very big text file (1 GB) and I see that there are few places where the http url field has a space there.

For example in the lines below we have space between "brad pitt" and "[30 wet=]". They should be changed to "bradpitt" and "[30wet=]" but they can occur in any url or trim_url. I am currently  finding these places using my program and then manually fixing it vim. Is there a way using awk/sed we can do it?

```
0.0 q:hello url:http://sapient.com/bapper/30/brad pitt/C345/surf trim_url:http://sapient.com/bapper/30/brad pitt/C345 rating:good
0.0 q:hello url:http://sick.com/bright/[30 wet=]/sound trim_url:http://sick.com/bright/[30 wet=]rating:good
```

What I tried to do was sed:

```
 sed -i -e 's/*http*[:space:]*/*http*/g' test.txt
```

Comment: Have you searched/tried anything yourself ? Always describe what you have tried in your post

Comment: Are you sure you don't need URI escape instead ? Like replacing spaces with `%20` ?

Comment: That maybe fine as well. I was not able to get the right regex but I tried like above different variants but I am not able to get it.

Comment: It's not that it  _may be fine_ to escape it with `%20`, it's that you will _destroy your URL list if you don't_: spaces are meaningful in URIs.

Comment: How do you (the script) know, that the first space in `/brad pitt/C345 rating:good` should be deleted (replaced by %20) and the second doesn't ?

Comment: I need the url for comparison purposes in my work so destruction is fine as long as it is consistent. Point is how to actually fix this as I already have utf-8 format.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl and a proper module to URI encode the URL:

```
perl -MURI::Escape -pe 's!(https?://)(.*)!$1 . uri_escape($2)!e' file
```

You even can replace the file *in place* with `-i` switch (just like sed) `perl -MURI::Escape -i -pe [...]`

### Output

```
0.0 q:hello url:http://sapient.com%2Fbapper%2F30%2Fbrad%20pitt%2FC345%2Fsurf%20trim_url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsapient.com%2Fbapper%2F30%2Fbrad%20pitt%2FC345%20rating%3Agood
0.0 q:hello url:http://sick.com%2Fbright%2F%5B30%20wet%3D%5D%2Fsound%20trim_url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsick.com%2Fbright%2F%5B30%20wet%3D%5Drating%3Agood
```

> URI::Escape - Percent-encode and percent-decode unsafe characters

## Note

As [msanford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114900/msanford) said in comments, spaces in a URL are meaningful. You can't decide to cut them without breaking the link in something that just become not reachable